# Getting This Code to Log outbound emails as well

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have used the code below to log inboud emails on an exchange outlook 2016 and 360. But there are a couple of problems I have not been able to resolve. I would like it to get it to log emails users sent (SMPT address) as well and place an identifier on the sheet I'm using showing if it is an outbound or inbound email. Also, at some point the macro freezes the Outlook app for a couple of secods which might get anoying. . Also  Lastly it would be could if the macro could, each day, send an email address the `Messagelog.xlsx` file.

```
Public WithEvents objMails As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set objMails = Outlook.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

Private Sub objMails_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strExcelFile As String
    Dim objExcelApp As Excel.Application
    Dim objExcelWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim objExcelWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim nNextEmptyRow As Integer
    Dim strColumnB As String
    Dim strColumnC As String
    Dim strColumnD As String
    Dim strColumnE As String

    If Item.Class = olMail Then
       Set objMail = Item
    End If

    'Specify the Excel file which you want to auto export the email list
    'You can change it as per your case
    strExcelFile = "C:\ETracker\MessageLog.xlsx"

    'Get Access to the Excel file
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objExcelApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    If Error <> 0 Then
       Set objExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If
    Set objExcelWorkBook = objExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(strExcelFile)
    Set objExcelWorkSheet = objExcelWorkBook.Sheets("Received")

    'Get the next empty row in the Excel worksheet
    nNextEmptyRow = objExcelWorkSheet.Range("B" & objExcelWorkSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    'Specify the corresponding values in the different columns
    strColumnB = objMail.SenderName
    strColumnC = objMail.SenderEmailAddress
    strColumnD = objMail.Subject
    strColumnE = objMail.ReceivedTime

    'Add the vaules into the columns
    objExcelWorkSheet.Range("A" & nNextEmptyRow) = nNextEmptyRow - 1
    objExcelWorkSheet.Range("B" & nNextEmptyRow) = strColumnB
    objExcelWorkSheet.Range("C" & nNextEmptyRow) = strColumnC
    objExcelWorkSheet.Range("D" & nNextEmptyRow) = strColumnD
    objExcelWorkSheet.Range("E" & nNextEmptyRow) = strColumnE

    'Fit the columns from A to E
    objExcelWorkSheet.Columns("A:E").AutoFit

    'Save the changes and close the Excel file
    objExcelWorkBook.Close SaveChanges:=True
End Sub
```

I would like to have one excel with the logged info showing, who sent the email, recipients, subject and time stamp, inbound/outbound mark

Comment: What have you tried in order to modify this code?  What specific problems are you having?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to log sent emails, then trap the Application.ItemSend event.  However, for automatically sending emails at a specific time of day you're very restricted with VBA macros. One hack is to use a recurring task with a reminder time and look for that specific task in the Application.Reminder event and fire off your macro at that time. Otherwise you'll have to design this as a COM Add-in and use a .NET timer component of some kind.